# Objective-C NSLog variant: __FILE__ without fullpath and output without datetime

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, nslog, pch

For debugging purposes I've added this code to my `.pch`.
Although I'm pretty satisfied with the output, I would like to improve the way I print the filename (without the full path) when I use `__FILE__` in the `DLog` definition.

I'm using `[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent]`

Maybe you could you suggest a cleaner/shorter way to do it?

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define DLog(...) NSLog(@"%@ %d %s %s", [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__)
    #define ALog(...) [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:[NSString stringWithCString:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] file:[NSString stringWithCString:__FILE__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] lineNumber:__LINE__ description:__VA_ARGS__]
#else
    #define DLog(...) do { } while (0)
    #ifndef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
        #define NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
    #endif
    #define ALog(...) NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#endif
```

**UPDATE**
If possible I would like also get rid of the datetime and app name `(i.e. 2012-05-30 16:23:29.795 AppName[11746:12203]`. Any suggestion?

Comment: the closest one I can think of is `printf` itself.

Comment: have you tried using printf function?

Comment: I have my own logging code which is shared by my C++ static library and my Objective-C++ application and I resorted to holding a `static const char *m_classname` in every class and a macro that passed it to the log function.  The method name is supplied using `__FUNCTION__`.  Works well.

Answer (score 1):

I think `[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent]` could become `@(__FILE__).lastPathComponent`, given the literal syntax that got introduced after you asked this question.